# Distinct in Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

in the below Query Benz table car_no is repeated. when I join and compare with other table car_no how do use distinct?

table 1: Cars
Table 2: benz

```
  join Benz bz on bz.car_no = cr.car_no
```

in the above car_no values in the Benz table are repeated. in Cars table car_no values unique. then how to join with distinct in query.

something i tried.

```
  join Benz bz on Distinct(bz.car_no) = cr.car_no
```

getting error.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You don't join on a `DISTINCT` value; `DISTINCT` is an operator that goes in the `SELECT`, and causes only *distinct* rows to be returned, or can be used in some aggregate functions, so only aggregate on *distinct* values. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Provide **consumable** sample data and expected results, and *explain* the logic.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the quick replay. I am new to DB queries. Here I am joining both tables and checking with car_no. taking unique records from Benz table based on car_no in car table

Comment: That doesn't explain anything I'm afraid. Also, if you are *new* to SQL Server, you should really be using a supported version; SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support way back in 2019.

Comment: Do you have separate tables for each car manufacturer? Have one common vehicles table instead.

Comment: There are multiple Benz rows per `car_no` and you only want to join one row per `car_no`? Then, which one? How do you decide which of the Benz rows matching the `car_no` to pick?